# Seek item within vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, search, binary-search

I have a vector of real values, sorted by increasing order.

These values can be within the range `[0, 1]`. Then I pick a value `x` within this range and I need to find which is the index of the smaller value greater or equal to `x`.

I can solve this problem by iterating over the whole array:

```
vector<double> values;
double x;

for (auto val : values)
{
    if (x <= values)
    {
        // found
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way to get the same result? I was thinking about a binary search, but how to implement it?

Comment: Not necessarily faster, but more readable: [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::distance(begin(values)
            , std::lower_bound(begin(values), end(values), x));
```

If the item doesn't exist, it'll give you an index one greater than that of the last element.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d78cd7574e44703d)

Comment: And why this method should be faster?

Comment: @Nick because it performs binary search with iterators of a random access category

Answer (score 1):

The function lower_bound might meet your demand,and you can use it like below:

```
iter =lower_bound(values.begin(),values.end(),x);
```

Comment: oh no,i took too much time to type those simple sentence because of my pool English (╯﹏╰)

Answer (score 0):

You know SO is not a site that you request someone to write you the code, so take this example of [std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) and make your way:

```
// binary_search example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::binary_search, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+9);                         // 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

  // using default comparison:
  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());

  std::cout << "looking for a 3... ";
  if (std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 3))
    std::cout << "found!\n"; else std::cout << "not found.\n";

  // using myfunction as comp:
  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), myfunction);

  std::cout << "looking for a 6... ";
  if (std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 6, myfunction))
    std::cout << "found!\n"; else std::cout << "not found.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

As Piotr said, this will not give you the index, but a yes/no answer. However, is should be the simplest approach, thus the fastest.

Comment: How is `binary_search` supposed to return an index?

Comment: From the question @PiotrSkotnicki, I understood that is enough to find the element or not.

Comment: *"and I need to find which is the index of the smaller value greater or equal to x."*

Comment: Oh damn it @PiotrSkotnicki, you are right! I was fooled by the example. Do you think I should delete the answer? Or maybe leave a note by your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) to directly access the items in a vector just like an array, instead of using an iterator to start from the begin. I assume you already know Binary Search. Implement it in an array is something you can find anywhere, so I won't explain it to you here. Just treat the vector as an array.

Comment: how would use of `operator[]` help to find the index of the desired element better than the solution in the question?

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk you don't need to start from the begin of the vector and scan through it. You can implement a binary search by starting at the middle of the vector, which runs in O(log n) instead of O(n).